# Android java Save Color

Tags: java, android, click, save

I have a button which has a default color, when I click on it it changes to yellow. Code looks like this.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        if (but[0] == 1) {
            ((Button) android.findViewById(R.id.pageOne)).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_white));
        } else {
            ((Button) android.findViewById(R.id.pageOne)).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_yellow));
        }
    }
```

Now I want this to be saved in the app. So when I restart that the button still shows yellow instead of the defaults. How to accomplish that?

Comment: you can use shared preferences to store a value so that next time you open the app you can get the last selected color.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `SharedPreferences`feature of Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1):

You open the Shared Preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("yourapplicationpackage", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and save the color:

```
 sharedprefs.edit().putString("buttoncolor", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_yellow)).apply();
```

You can get your color with:

```
Color buttoncolor= sharedprefs.getString("buttoncolor, "defaultcoloryoulike");
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks alot.
So does the last step automatically check the changed color?

Comment: And what excatly do you mean with "buttoncolor"?

Comment: the last step gets the last inserted color in the shared preferences. The "buttoncolor" is the tag used to save it in the shared preferences. you could use another tag but to get the saved color you need to use the same tag.

Comment: just to be sure inside "defaultcoloryoulike" goes getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_yellow)).apply(); ?